# "Circular Reference" exception when serializing database object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, javascriptserializer

I get an error stating that a *circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type*. I believe it has something to do with my Database and how I have PK's and FK's set.

```
    public string GetSongs(int playlistId)
    {
        var songs = (from song in _db.Songs where song.PlaylistId == playlistId select song).ToList();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(songs); // ERROR MESSAGE HERE
        return json;
    }
```

Here is a picture of my DB schema:

[image]

Comment: While this isn't an answer: consider *not* exposing the database model directly. Having a separate object graph (and mapping to such) would avoid this issue and provide much more fine-grained/flexible response results as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Code first then avoid using `virtual` keyword from `User` property in `Playlist` Model and `Playlist` from `Song` model.
Because `Playlist` auto load your `User` model and thus again your `Playlist` is by `User` and loop goes on.

Comment: I just tried removing the virtual keyword but still having the same error

Comment: then remove virtual form Playlist property from Song model as well

Answer (score 1):

You have *very* circular references. Your `Users` have `PlayLists`, and each `PlayList` has a user and also a list of `Songs`, each of which be in a `PlayList`.

1. To serialize `User 1`, you will have to serialize `PlayList 1`.
2. To serialize `PlayList 1`, you have to serialize its `User`, which is `User 1`
3. To serialize `User 1`, you will have to serialize `PlayList 1`.

etc.

As has been stated elsewhere, the solution is to not directly expose your data model. What you want to serialize is something that contains the foreign keys, not references to Entity Framework models. So your `UserDTO` object might contain an Id, Username, Password, and a list of PlayList IDs, not a list of `PlayList`. Each `PlayListDTO` would contain an Id, `UserId`, and a list of `SongId`, etc.